# How to initialize Entry widget with blank value in tkinter instead of 0.0?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am beginning in tkinter programming an do not understand why my Entry begin with 0.0 as initial value? i desire to have it blank when this program run. How i can do that?

```
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import ttk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x400')

#X-AXIS LABEL FRAME
x_frame = ttk.Frame(window)
x_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
var_label = ttk.Label(x_frame, text='X - AXIS')
var_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

#X-AXIS VARIABLES FRAME
var_list = ['t', 'V', 'T', 'RPM']
x_check_list = []

for index, variable in enumerate(var_list):
    x_check_list.append(tk.IntVar(value=0))
    ttk.Checkbutton(x_frame, variable=x_check_list[index], text=variable).grid(row=index+1, sticky='w')

#X-AXIS LIMITS LABEL
x_limits_frame = ttk.Frame(window)
x_limits_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
ttk.Label(x_limits_frame, text='X - LIMITS').grid(row=0, column=0)

#X-AXIS LIMITS ENTRY
ttk.Label(x_limits_frame, text='INF:').grid(row=1, column=0)
x_min_lim = tk.DoubleVar()
ttk.Entry(master=x_limits_frame, textvariable=x_min_lim, width=5).grid(row=1, column=1)

ttk.Label(x_limits_frame, text='SUP:').grid(row=2, column=0)
x_max_lim = tk.DoubleVar()
ttk.Entry(master=x_limits_frame, textvariable=x_max_lim, width=5).grid(row=2, column=1)

#Y-AXIS LABEL FRAME
y_frame = ttk.Frame(window)
y_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
ttk.Label(y_frame, text='Y - AXIS').grid(row=0, column=0)


#Y-AXIS VARIABLES FRAME
y_check_list = []

for index, variable in enumerate(var_list):
    y_check_list.append(tk.IntVar(value=0))
    ttk.Checkbutton(y_frame, variable=y_check_list[index], text=variable).grid(row=index+1, sticky='w')

#Y-AXIS LIMITS LABEL FRAME
y_limits_frame = ttk.Frame(window)
y_limits_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
ttk.Label(y_limits_frame, text='Y - LIMITS').grid(row=0, column=0)

#Y-AXIS LIMITS ENTRY LABEL
ttk.Label(y_limits_frame, text='INF:').grid(row=1, column=0)
y_min_lim = tk.DoubleVar()
ttk.Entry(master=y_limits_frame, textvariable=y_min_lim, width=5).grid(row=1, column=1)

ttk.Label(y_limits_frame, text='SUP:').grid(row=2, column=0)
y_max_lim = tk.DoubleVar()
ttk.Entry(master=y_limits_frame, textvariable=y_max_lim, width=5).grid(row=2, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

I have another code which works like expected, there's no default value in the entry area.

```
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import ttk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk

#window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('mile to km')
window.geometry('300x150')

#tittle
title_label = ttk.Label(master=window, text='km to miles', font='Arial 24 bold')
title_label.pack()

#input field
input_frame = ttk.Frame(master=window)
entry_int = tk.IntVar()
entry = ttk.Entry(master=input_frame, textvariable=entry_int)
button = ttk.Button(master=input_frame, text='convert', command=lambda: output_string.set(entry_int.get()*1.61))
entry.pack(side='left')
button.pack(side='right', padx=10)
input_frame.pack(pady=10)

#output
output_string = tk.StringVar()
output_label = ttk.Label(master=window, text='Output', font='Arial 24', textvariable=output_string)
output_label.pack()

#run
window.mainloop()
```

I tried changing grid to pack, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `tk.StringVar()` instead of a `tk.DoubleVar()` for the `Entry` `textvariable`

```
x_min_lim = tk.StringVar()  # defaults to an empty string
ttk.Entry(master=x_limits_frame, textvariable=x_min_lim, width=5).grid(row=1, column=1)

# you can do the same for 'x_max_lim', naturally
```

The caveat here is that you may need to do some conversion to a numeric datatype here and there

---

As an aside, if you need to refer to a widget later, you should *always* instantiate it separately from `grid`, `pack`, or `place`, like so:

```
# declare a variable called 'min_entry' (for example)
min_entry = ttk.Entry(master=y_limits_frame, textvariable=y_min_lim, width=5)
# add this widget to the grid
min_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

This is because the geometry manager methods (`grid`, `pack`, `place`) all return `None`, so if you don't separate them, `min_entry` in this example would always be equal to `None` instead of the `Entry` widget!

This isn't a problem here specifically since you're not storing references to your `Entry` widgets, but it's food for thought!